# Fetch selected id's record at top in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have one mongo collection which has thousands of record and I am fetching the record with mongoose pagination with 10 record per page limit. Now My user has selected 15 of record from and I have these id's in other collection. Now what I want when My user visit this page next time the these 15 record should show at top and of course user can other record of the collection as well through pagination.

Comment: You should add some code to help us gain context, also mention you stack. When you say, "when user visits the page next time", how can we understand how is the user accessing the page in the first place?

Comment: @saibbyweb I have mention that i am inserting user selected record in other collection with userid and id of main collection. So I can fetch all the selected id of user